# What's the simplest way of inlining a variable?

Tags: global-command

I've recently refactored `vim-colors-solarized` and I've stumbled on a code like this

```
let s:foo = s:bar " used in multiple places
" ... many lines
let s:goo = s:boo " used in multiple places
```

How can I inline all usages of such variables automatically easily. Of course I can write a function to do that. But maybe something like `g/let s:."=\s*s:.*/normal dw"adWdW"vdW" | exe "g/@v/s/@a/@v/g" | d` in which I mean find all lines matching a pattern, yank variable name to be inlined into register `a` it's value into register `v`. Then inside of this global command execute another global command on all lines after the match substituting variable with its value and removing initially matched line.

Comment: Write the function (or a macro). Trying to cram it into one messy line is bound to be error prone and run into edge cases.

Comment: In other words, I’d argue that your way is one of the more complex, in that it is hard to understand at first glance. A function or macro can be simpler, broken down into pieces, &c. If by simplest you mean something specific, please clarify.

Comment: You see the problem is that I have a policy of either doing the best thing I possibly can or nothing at all. In this case If I would write a function it would definitely not be done in vimscript and it would be able to do inlining of any variable in vimscript. And to do that I would have to start with a parser. To much work for such a specific and rare case.

Answer (score 1):

After expanding on the other [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25892/10033), I thought I should also share my own personal solution for these renaming/refactoring type problems.

```
nnoremap * :'<,'>s/\C\<<C-r><C-w>\>//g<C-f>$F/i
vnoremap * y:'<,'>s/\C\<<C-r>"\>//g<C-f>$F/i
nnoremap & :%s/\C\<<C-r><C-w>\>//g<C-f>$F/i
vnoremap & y:%s/\C\<<C-r>"\>//g<C-f>$F/i
```

This provides two handy dual-mode key mappings.  To replace all instances of `foo` in a document, while your cursor is over an instance of `foo` enter:

`&bar`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

To replace all instances of not-strictly-word `foo-bar` simply make a visual selection and enter `&bar`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

If you want to limit your renaming to a single section (e.g. a function or class), define the area you want to operate in with a visual selection first—I generally use <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> (which technically yanks the selected area, but serves our purpose)—then much as above, while hovering or visually selecting a word, enter:

`*bar`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

#### How it works

Using the remapping for <kbd>*</kbd> as it is the more complex, pressing it will cause an ex command line to appear, which will look something like this:

```
:'<,'>s/\C\<foo\>/XXX/g
```

Where `XXX` represents where your cursor will be, allowing you to type a replacement and press enter immediately.

#### Caveats

The `\<` and `\>` match the beginning and ending of words respectively, this can sometimes be undesirable (e.g. if you are replacing `foo()`  with `bar(1)`) and in those cases it is necessary to remove one of the anchors.

```
:'<,'>s/\C\<foo()/XXX/g
```

Some people may already use the <kbd>*</kbd> key binding, whose default action serves a similar purpose (finding the next instance of the word under the cursor), obviously you can bind to something else—and let me know if you find a reliable cross-platform way to bind Shift-Alt-* or some such, otherwise `<leader>*` doesn't do anything terribly useful.

#### Bonus

I have found that this binding can work (to a limited degree) in some Vim emulators, e.g. VsVim for Visual Studio—if it defined in simpler terms

```
nnoremap * :'<,'>s/\C\<<c-r><c-w>\>/
nnoremap & :%s/\C\<<c-r><c-w>\>/
```

It can also be modified (on the fly, or as part of the binding) to use everybody's favorite Vim plugin author's magic `:S` search, and therefore replace `foo` with `bar`, `Foo` with `Bar`, and `FOO` with `BAR`.  As someone else put it, "We do not deserve Tim Pope."  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23144847/912236

#### Improvements

If anyone would like to write a more complex version that automatically dropped the begin/end of word anchors, when the search string didn't begin/end with a word: that would be great.

There are other instance: `class.foo` vs `var foo`, and `# comment foo` where differentiation might be handy, and there are times when it might be nice to have a copy of the original text duplicated so you can make a tiny edit.  I generally find these cases to be less common/annoying that you might think.  If you want that kind of smart refactoring, use an IDE.

Comment: @DBK, thanks for the em dashes, I get lazy without my Mac and forget Alt-0150/Alt-0151 can make en/em dashes on Windows.  I should really make an AHK macro to emulate the Mac method.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use search and `cgn` combination for inlining and repeating with `.`

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> visually selects the next match of a search (think of it as the **g**raphic version of **n**ext)

<kbd>c</kbd> changes; i.e. erases to the point designated by the follow keystroke(s).

<kbd>**.**</kbd> (dot) was something I only recently learned after 25 years of Vi/Vim.  It repeats the last action you performed, though I suspect the exact definition is more complex than that.

If you put all this together, it turns out that you can replace all instances of `foo` with `bar`, by entering:

`/foo`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`cgnbar`<kbd>Esc</kbd>`.....` (one dot per replacement or just hold it until done).

Certainly an interesting and useful joining of 4 or so normally separate functions to serve 1 purpose.

This method could be used to automatically replace words as Orwellophile's answer does, just substitute `*` for the *search* portion.  *e.g.:* `*cgnbar`<kbd>Esc</kbd> if your cursor was over the word `foo`.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Your answer was flagged for being too short. I think your answer is actually ok, but it could be improved by explaining *how* to use `cgn` for this particular use case in detail. What would you search for? What would you replace it with? Which keystrokes would you use? Thanks for contributing and I hope you have a great time here!